# Visual Basic Login page causing an error (Error BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents....)

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple mysql authentication login page on my asp.net webform.
I'm getting the same error every time I try to run my page and I have no idea how to solve it. Here is the error:

> Error  BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.  Test1   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test1\Account\Login.aspx.vb 10  Active

Here is my code behind the error:

```
Protected Sub Login_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login.Authenticate
    Dim Username As String = Login.UserName
    Dim password As String = Login.Password
    Dim SQLCommand As String = "SELECT level FROM users WHERE (username= '" &
                    Username & "' AND pw = '" & password & "')"
    Dim level As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("test").ToString()
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQLCommand, con)
    con.Open()
    If cmd.ExecuteScalar() = Nothing Then
        level = ""
    Else
        level = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End If
    con.Close()
    If level = "B" Or level = "G" Then
        Session("Level") = level
        Session("User") = Username
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username, False)
    Else
        Login.FailureText = "Try Again"
    End If    
End Sub
```

I first thought it was because I used `=` instead of 'Is' in `If cmd.ExecuteScalar() = Nothing Then`

But changing it doesn't really affect it.

Comment: Show your `aspx` ...

Comment: `WHERE (username= '" & Username & "' AND pw = '" & password & "')"`  This is SO wrong on SO many levels. Have you really not heard of [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)?  Are you seriously storing plaintext passwords?

Comment: BC30506 can present when attempting to handle an event on a control inside a repeater, which don't get created in the designer file. E.g., a DataGrid within a Repeater. Seems unlikely that's what happened here, but noting in case someone else had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type

In your page directive you need to put a CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"

e.g

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```