# Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET Website error: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I'm new to the job and trying to get accustomed to VB.NET and Visual Studio 2008. I came from VS 2015 - 2017 and C#.

I downloaded a project from Subversion Source Control and I tried to run it. I get this weird error that reads: "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base type". I tried several solutions around the web and SO without avail. I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674574/handles-clause-requires-a-withevents-variable-defined-in-the-containing-type-or), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780240/visual-basic-login-page-causing-an-error-error-bc30506-handles-clause-requires) and [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1147454.aspx?BC30506%20Handles%20clause%20requires%20a%20WithEvents%20variable%20defined%20in%20the%20containing%20type%20or%20one%20of%20its%20base%20types%20) without any luck. Some of the solutions has to do with the aspx.designer.vb file but unlike projects, VS 2008 ASP.NET websites doesn't have these type of files. I tried to re-create the button and the code behind with no luck. The error persists and the error only refers to one button in particular. Others buttons in the same page are working fine.

How I'm supposed to fix this? Please! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it is impossible to say why the error occurred but here's one of the reasons that might cause this issue.

**You are trying to use evets of a type that is not declared to use events of**

Consider the below sample :

```
Dim txbx as New TextBox
```

Here I created a new instance of the type `TextBox`. As we know a textbox has may events, so if you try to access the events of the above declared textbox as follows :

```
Private sub txtbx_TextChanged(……….) Handles txtbx.TextChanged
```

Then you will get the error.In order to access the events of a code-behind declared type/control, you must `WithEvents` when you define/declare the variable of the type :

```
Dim WithEvents txtbx as New TextBox
```

Now you can easily access all the evets of the type. As I said earlier that this may not be your issue but if it is, then I hope it helps :)

**or**

create anew page , copy-paste all codes from previous page(except page directives from HTML ) and rebuild your project ...

Comment: Hi Zack. Thanks for your fast reply. The buttons that works, as well as the button that gives the error, are declared nowhere. For what I know, they get declared in the aspx.designer.vb in Web Forms projects, but this is no project but a website, so I don't have those files. These buttons doesn't appear to be declared anywhere in the project, nor even the ones that actually works. Can you clarify where these buttons should be declared?

Comment: They should be declared either in .aspx file or could even be declared in the .vb file ….

Comment: If you have anything else to say which may be too broad, you can drop it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170558/simple-chats)

Comment: Ok I will be writing some words in that chat. Thank you.

Comment: Zack, thank you so much for your help through the chat. I changed the name of the page that had the problem and the error was gone after a rebuild. I was able then to change it back to the original name. Very weird stuff. Please, edit your answer so I can vote it up and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SamyCode, recheck my answer